# JSON-Server not returning single child element by ID

Tags: json, rest, json-server

I'm trying to get [Json-Server](https://github.com/typicode/json-server) (v 0.12.1) working without the need for middleware or using it as a component - I already have something that works fine if I'm going to take the time to manually code all the endpoints. I'm attracted to the simplistic route config, and I believe I should be able to use it without requiring anything but a `routes.json` and `db.json` (letting me remove a lot of boilerplate express stuff).

My db.json:

```
  "users": [
    {
      "userId": 1,
      "favoriteColor": "red"
    },
    {
      "userId": 2,
      "favoriteColor": "blue"
    },
    {
      "userId": 3,
      "favoriteColor": "green"
    }
  ]
```

My routes.json:

```
{
    "/api/users": "/users",
    "/api/users/:userId": "/users/:userId"
}
```

I want to be able to make a GET call to: `http://localhost:3000/api/users/2` and get

```
{
  "userId": 2,
  "favoriteColor": "blue"
}
```

in return. However, I always just get `{}`.

Trying to use some suggestions from SO which either change the data structure (which I don't have control over) or using filters (which returns an array, not an object) are no-go for me.

Does anyone know why this seemingly-simply route is not working? I believe I'm following the [custom route guidelines](https://github.com/typicode/json-server#add-custom-routes). I'm starting the server with `json-server --watch ./api/db.json --routes ./api/routes.json`, and hitting `http://localhost:3000/api/users` returns exactly what I expect, so I know the `routes.json` file and `db.json` file are both being picked up successfully.

Thank you!

Comment: I was reading the docs of json-server and it looks like you can get the object without defining the second route. Did you try that?

Comment: @funcoding I have now, thanks! If I omit the second endpoint and simply call http://localhost:3000/api/users/2 I get a 404, unfortunately. And changing "userId" to "id" (in case there is an assumed-convention) also doesn't seem to help.

Comment: Well, again. Based on the previous db.json file, you got some default routes. Did you start the server using `--routes`?

Comment: Did that work for you?

Comment: @funcoding Yes, I started it with `json-server --watch ./api/db.json --routes ./api/routes.json`

Comment: Did you try using my db.json and routes.json?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I gotta working starting the server with: 
`json-server --watch db.json --routes routes.json`

db.json

```
{
  "users": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "first_name": "Sebastian",
      "last_name": "Eschweiler",
      "email": "sebastian@codingthesmartway.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "first_name": "Steve",
      "last_name": "Palmer",
      "email": "steve@codingthesmartway.com"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "Ann",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "email": "ann@codingthesmartway.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

routes.json

```
{
    "/api/users": "/users",
    "/api/users/:id": "/users/:id"
}
```

Comment: I had to scratch my head to figure out why yours works and mine doesn't when we have the same routes... but it turns out that having an `id` attribute *is* required by convention (as opposed to `userId`). I thought I had tested that but apparently I messed up the test. Thank you for helping force me to take another look at that.

Comment: @tengen Glad could help!